# Rational functions Set R(s)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand the Rational functions Set $\Bbb R(s)$, we can see this set as
$$\Bbb R(s)=\{\frac{a(s)}{b(s)}:a(s) \in \Bbb R[s], b(s) \in \Bbb R[s]- \{0\}\}$$
so I have these questions: What is the dimension of $\Bbb R(s)$ defined over $\Bbb R$ and What is the dimension of $\Bbb R(s)$ defined over $\Bbb R(s)$.

If someone can explain this please, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Any ideas? $\phantom{}$

Comment: I have problems understanding the dimension, for example if R(s) is dimension infinite? and then respect R still infinite?

Comment: $R(s)$ contains the subspace (and subalgebra) $R[s]$. Can you think of an $R$-basis for $R[s]$? Also, by $R$ do you mean $\Bbb R$, the real numbers?

Comment: I would like to understand this concept of dimension with functions, what is a basis of R(S) ? {1,t,t^2,...,t^n}? yes is over reals

Comment: Type `$\Bbb R$` to get $\Bbb R$. You're mixing up letters writing $t$ down. The set $\{1,s,s^2,\cdots\}$ is indeed a basis for $\Bbb R[s]$, but not for $\Bbb R(s)$. In any case it shows that $\Bbb R(s)$ is infinite-dimensional. If you want to be more specific and say its dimension is countably infinite, you'll need to understand partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Ok, It is not clear for me that but I`m going to search more information about this, ty

Comment: As for your second question: if $F$ is any field, then what is the dimension of $F$ as a vector space over $F$ itself?